# Unity change vertex normals on collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, normals

I want to change the floor's vertex normals' direction as the ball is rolling on the floor. I just need some direction on how to achieve this.

So far this is the direction that I'm heading:

1. Make a copy of all the vertex normals of the floor on start.
2. On collision get the contact point and raycast/spherecast/boxcast to get the affected vertices. (Set variable offset to control how much vertices I want to be affected by the casting)
3. Find normals related to the vertices.
4. Rotate the affected normals parrallel to the ball's closest surface point.
5. As ball moves away from affected's floor's vertices, slowly return the floor normals back to original direction. (Set a variable to control the movement speed of the normal's rotating back to original direction)

[image: normals]

I just need help figuring out which type of casting to use and how to rotate the normals parallel to the ball's surface. This is for a mobile platform so performance is a must.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm late to the party, but: consider just changing the normals in your vertex shader. It'll be significantly faster than modifying them on the CPU. I used a similar method to split (3D) asteroids in half in an Asteroids clone.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you'd go about modifying the normals:

```
Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
Vector3[] normals = mesh.normals;
```

You'd want to use the `vertices` list to figure out which indexes to modify (presumably also needing to convert from local space to world space). You could then raycast from the worldspace coordinate to the ball's center,<sup>1</sup> and use the `raycasthit.normal` to figure out what the angle to the ball is.

Some clever vector math from *there* to figure out the new normal for your plane:

1. Find the [vector perpendicular](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/133183) between `hit.normal` and `Vector3.Up`: this vector will be parallel to the plane.  *If the two vectors are parallel*, dump out: your normal is unchanged (or should be returned to its original value, which will be the same vector as the raycast to find the sphere).
2. Find the vector perpendicular to that vector and `hit.normal`: this vector will be your new normal.

<sup>1</sup> Actually, you'll want to know how far *down* from the ball's center you should target, otherwise, you'll get the most extreme offsets as the ball moves farther away from the plane. So you want the ball's position on X and Z, but a fixed offset up from the plane for Y. This won't be too difficult to calculate.

Comment: Hmmm... You've got something there.

Comment: I can copy the current bounds of the ball to a temporary new bounds and scale a little. Then offset the temp bounds down halfway to the floor. From there I can find out the vertices position globally. Loop through the vertices and see if they are in bounds withing the temporary bounds. This way I can get which normals will be affected. 

Also if the normals are not in bounds but were changed I can rotate them back to their original position.

I will have to research and test out how to get the perpendicular vector.

Comment: This will eliminate the need for me raycast.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Read my footnote.

Comment: @Draco18s _"**slowly** return the floor normals back to original direction."_ implies that there should be something cross frames. Like if the ball rolls fast, if leave a trace in the (for example) grass. So there should be something to keep track on the normal of each vertex.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I'll let the asker decide if that's what they want or not. You might be right, but they haven't said so.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like:

Create a texture for the normals. Each pixel is a normal of a vertex(like a grid). Calculate the correspoding coord between the 3d ball and the position of the normal in the texture and draw a ball/circle/sprite on it (like a sprite) each frame. Then you could use a compute shader to revert them slowy to the default up vector.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This method sounds very taxing for a mobile application. Correct me if I'm wrong but I haven't had the chance to learn about CG scripting. The surface of the actual floor have about one to two dozen vertices. I figured it would be better performance to manipulate verts' normals instead.

Comment: If you only use a `dozen` vertices, the texture containing the normals would be very small. I think this will run perfectly on a mobile. It would perform better than checking each vertex normal on the cpu and upload it each frame.

Comment: @user1105430 This might be useful: [How we made trees move and react to wind and explosion](https://imgur.com/gallery/WcGUC)

Comment: I fail to see why this wouldn't be done only by a very simple vertex shader. Pass the ball center and radius as constant, and from there everything is pretty simple to compute, it could even be done per pixel afaik.

Comment: @BriceV. This comment _"As ball moves away from affected's floor's vertices, slowly return the floor normals back to original direction"_ which implies the state of the normal must be saved somewhere.. Either the path of the ball or the normals of the floor. This means on the cpu, that all vertex normals must be changed and uploaded each frame, or alter them with a compu shader directly on the gpu.

Comment: I'll definitely have to take the time and learn CG programming if it saves on performance. The internet is vast. Can you reference me to where I should be looking in to?

Comment: First hit for compute shaders: http://kylehalladay.com/blog/tutorial/2014/06/27/Compute-Shaders-Are-Nifty.html

Comment: So the revert back to initial position is based on time rather than distance? If so then yes, you need to store the state. I'm pretty sure compute shaders are out of the question for a broad mobile user base at this time (but maybe OP has a specific target in mind, or plans to release in a few years?). It could be done with a texture as proposed by @JeroenvanLangen, but probably needs to be done on the cpu. You probably only need to compute the time factor per vertex, then do the lerp between the 2 normals (and the computation of the bent normal) into the shader.

Comment: I don't think a compu shader will be a problem. it relies on the same hardware technique as executing fragment shaders. The texture is very small (the length/width of the vertex grid) The most expensive part is copying memory from cpu/gpu which will not be the case. _" then do the lerp between the 2 normals"_ sounds easy, but will only work if the ball rolls in one direction.